# C Error: undefined reference to '_itoa'

Tags: c, itoa

I'm trying to convert an integer to a character to write to a file, using this line:

```
fputc(itoa(size, tempBuffer, 10), saveFile);
```

and I receive this warning and message:

**warning:** implicit declaration of 'itoa'

undefined reference to '_itoa'

I've already included stdlib.h, and am compiling with:

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -ansi
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I am guessing that itoa may not be present in the standard C library you are using.  You could try specifying the flag `-fpermissive` to see if the code works.

Comment: There's no such function as `itoa` in the "official" standard library. Apparently the standard library you are using does not provide `itoa`. Your `-pedantic` and `-ansi` flags will not help anything. Quite the opposite, they can actually make things worse by hiding non-standard functions (I don't know whether they really do that). Try compiling without them.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`itoa` is not part of the standard. I suspect either `-ansi` is preventing you from using it, or it's not available at all.

I would suggest using `sprintf()`

If you go with the c99 standard, you can use `snprintf()` which is of course safer.

```
char buffer[12];
int i = 20;
snprintf(buffer, 12,"%d",i);
```

Comment: You need a bigger buffer to handle the negative sign.

Comment: @RocketRoy it was actually simply an example. The value `20` in the example fits just fine in a `char[10]` and that's the buffer size the OP was using. But yes, a signed 32 bit int would require `char[12]` to handle the sign and `\0`

Comment: @BrianRoach while you are perfectly correct, for the sake of people who like to copy paste I have changed the size of the buffer in the example.

Comment: Brian's original answer illustrates the fact of the matter. Assuming that `int` would fit into a 12 byte string is completely incorrect, and if put out as fact, it could mislead people. For example, on AVR 8-bit systems, 'int's are often 16-bit (2- byte).

Answer (score 2):

This here tells you that during the compilation phase `itoa` is unknown:

> warning: implicit declaration of
>   'itoa'

so if this function is present on your system you are missing a header file that declares it. The compiler then supposes that it is a function that takes an unspecific number of arguments and returns an `int`.

This message from the loader phase

> undefined reference to '_itoa'

explains that also the loader doesn't find such a function in any of the libraries he knows of.

So you should perhaps follow Brian's advice to replace `itoa` by a standard function.