# Invalid conversion from 'int' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]

Tags: arduino-uno

[image]

When I run the code, I get an `Invalid conversion from 'int' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]` error, and I cannot figure out what's wrong.

I'm new to arduino and I have this project and I cannot understand a single thing.

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors/data. Instead post the code/errors/data as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the compiler cannot cast int to char*.
The reason is that coulourDistance is of type 'int' and SAMPLES[i][4] seems to be a 'char*' (i.e. a string) - tell me if I'm wrong! If so, the error comes from the assignment `SAMPLES[i][4] = coulourDistance;`.
You can replace it with `sprintf(SAMPLES[i][4], "%d", coulourDistance);` as explained in this post [I use sprintf as follows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970439/gcc-error-undefined-reference-to-itoa)